# sIFR 3 text stretched in IE9

Tags: sifr, sifr3

In IE9 the sIFR3 (r436) rendered text on my site is stretched. Clicking on the text causes it to render properly.

I've tried changing the compatibility mode but without success. Anyone else having this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our tests we discovered that the problem had to do with the version of Flash, specifically 10.2 (reproduced on 10.2.152.26) on a Vista machine.  10.0, 10.1 and 10.3 were all fine and did not stretch the text.

There's even a fix in the Flash Player 10.3 that addresses improper resizing when wmode=transparent: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/901/cpsid_90194.html

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need wmode transparency or opaque turn that off - that's what i found to be causing our problem in ie9...then it appeared fine.

unfortunately we needed to have things sat over the top of the flash so i had to have those setting on...in that case the only workaround i've found so far to sort it out is to call the sifr without wmode settings (transparency/opaque), then in the onReplacement sifr callback create a clone of the flash element with the wmode set on and then remove the original. not ideal but it works (although there is a small lag when it's recreating the element of course - you can mess about with css display properties to mitigate the effects of this)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to keep the wmode so using the callback function may be the answer - will give it a go. Have had some improvement setting the sIFR.forceWidth parameter to true, but hasn't completely resolved it.